# appending to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add make a pandas dataframe with two columns : read_id and score

I am using the following code :

```
    reads_array = []
    for x in Bio.SeqIO.parse("inp.fasta","fasta"):
             reads_array.append(x)

    columns = ["read_id","score"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)
    df = df.fillna(0)

    for x in reads_array:
                alignments=pairwise2.align.globalms("ACTTGAT",str(x.seq),2,-1,-.5,-.1)
                sorted_alignments = sorted(alignments, key=operator.itemgetter(2),reverse = True)
                read_id = x.name
                score = sorted_alignments[0][2]
                df['read_id'] = read_id
                df['score'] = score
```

But this does not work. Can you suggest a way of generating the dataframe df

Comment: Well all you're doing is overwriting that column with whatever is happening in your loop, you want to assign the entire contents of each column in one ago so try building each column and then assign at the end

Comment: It appears that `reads_array` is a list populated with tuple pairs.  When you run your second loop, I don't understand `x.seq` and `x.name`.  Shouldn't that raise an error?  Also, please provide some sample data (e.g. 5 rows).

Comment: >read_id_1 ATTTTGG >read_id_2 TTGGATT and so on in fasta format. x.name is read_id_1, read_id_2 etc. and x.seq are the sequemnces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top make sure you have

```
import numpy as np
```

Then replace the code you shared with

```
reads_array = []
for x in Bio.SeqIO.parse("inp.fastq", "fastq"):
    reads_array.append(x)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(reads_array), 2)), columns=["read_id", "score"])

for index, x in enumerate(reads_array): 
    alignments = pairwise2.align.globalms("ACTTGAT", str(x.seq), 2, -1, -.5, -.1)
    sorted_alignments = sorted(alignments, key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
    read_id = x.name
    score = sorted_alignments[0][2]
    df.loc[index, 'read_id'] = read_id
    df.loc[index, 'score'] = score
```

The main problem with your original code was two things:

1) Your dataframe had 0 rows

2) df['column_name'] refers to the entire column, not a single cell, so when you execute df['column_name'] = value, all cells in that column get set to that value

Answer (score 0):

`df['read_id']` and `df['score']` is Series. So if you want to iterate `reads_array` and calculate some value, then assign it to df's columns, try following:

```
for i, x in enumerate(reads_array):
    ...
    df.ix[i]['read_id'] = read_id
    df.ix[i]['score'] = score
```